# edit the sql schema compare (.scmp) so that certain tables and stored procs are filtered

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-devops, compare

Since a few months we are working with a (VS) database solution for our SQL Server objects.
Of course, the Schema Compare is a feature we often use.

I've got the question of the team if we can modify the schema compare script (.scmp) so that certain tables and stored procs are excluded from the compare. This script will be part of the solution and used by all team members.

eg. every table with '_BU' (wildcard) in the name. Example: DimCustomer_BU20220419
This means a backup table -> should be excluded

I saw that this is perfectly possible with APEX SQL but I'd rather stay within VS/Devops.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a comparison view you can unmark the objects you want to exclude and save .scmp

Comment: Hello Serg, that I know... But what with a wildcard '_BUxxxxxxxx' etc.

Comment: Not sure if .scmp supports any wildcard syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no:

- Yes, you can exclude the desired objects from the comparison, either in the source or the target side, or both (see scmp below)
- No, you can't used wildcards

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SchemaComparison>
  <Version>10</Version>
  <ExcludedSourceElements>
    <SelectedItem Type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlProcedure, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <Name>dbo</Name>
      <Name>MySuperbStoredProc</Name>
    </SelectedItem>
  </ExcludedSourceElements>
  <ExcludedTargetElements>
    <SelectedItem Type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlProcedure, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <Name>dbo</Name>
      <Name>MySuperbStoredProc</Name>
    </SelectedItem>
  </ExcludedTargetElements>
</SchemaComparison>
```

AFAIK, there is no documentation on the `.scmp` XML schema, so changing it by hand doesn't look feasible. The easiest way to modify it is by running the comparison visually inside Visual Studio SSDT, and right click on the changes that you want to exclude. It can be done at the desired level, for ex. the table or column level.

There is no easy solution for using wildcards, but you can do something programmatic by using the DAC classes, for example [Schema Comparison class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.compare.schemacomparison?view=sql-dacfx-150). For example, you can programmatically load a `.scmp` file, apply some changes, and save the updated version. Not the easiest, but feasible.